# Flutter- how to replace a tabbar with 'Year-month' format

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hi~
I want to replace multiple tab bar names with 'yyyy-month' date format.
Here's my code below which I used List to display multiple tab bar names. 
Anyone who could handle my issue? 
Please refer to my code below :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:everyday/widgets/image_grid.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = List.generate(
      10, (index) => Tab(text: 'Tab $index'));

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
          return Center(
            child: ImageGrid(),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you are assigning the name of the tab is

```dart
final List<Tab> myTabs = List.generate(
      10, (index) => Tab(text: 'Tab $index'));
```

You just need to generate the text based on a date (which I assume is today)

**EDIT2**

I tried this code and it works fine for me.
Package intl is needed for DateFormat function

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

```dart
final List<Tab> myTabs = List.generate(
      10, (index) {
        var now = DateTime.now();
        var date = DateTime(now.year, now.month + index, now.day);
        String dateDisplay = DateFormat('yMMM').format(date);
        return Tab(text: dateDisplay);
      }
      );
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way ( to define `now` outside and use it in `.generate` but it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I've got an error that says 'only static members can be accessed in initializers' with a red underlined '&formatter'. Have any ideas to figure this out? @CarlosSR

Comment: I edited the definitions of now and formatter to make them final.

Comment: @MinKyeongKim did this solved your list generation?

Comment: still having the same error. I added intl package and defined now and formatter though. @CarlosSR

Comment: @MinKyeongKim all set